# How can I extract rtsp data into MediaCodec

Tags: java, android, rtsp, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I am having issues with MediaPlayer playing my RTSP stream, so i decided to use the lower level APIs - MediaExtractor and MediaCodec.

The problem is that the setDataSource() method for MediaExtractor does not accept an RTSP stream.

So, my question is, how can I get the rtsp data into the MediaCodec input buffers ?

Comment: Afaik, MediaCodec only needs the encoded data with proper codec headers [frame headers] not the RTSP/RTP headers. I have worked with RTP and I retrieved the payload i.e. encoded video data and fed it to the mediacodec decoder. Why do you need to send the rtsp related data to the mediacodec decoder input buffers?

Comment: I dont need rtsp data, I guess that was just bad wording.  What I meant was as you described - encoded data (from an RTSP source), not necessarily the RTP headers.  Is it easy to extract the RTP headers ?